# How can I set the x-axis (timestamp) and y-axis(heartbeat) into my chart and the data is from the server using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, chart.js

How can I set the x-axis (timestamp) and y-axis(heartbeat) into my chart and the data is from the server? 
In the server that I connected, it can retrieve the data successfully but my chart can't display any data at all.

```
window.onload = function () {

let dps = []; // dataPoints
let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    zoomEnabled: true,
    title :{
        text: "Heart Beat"
    },
    axisX: {
        title: "timestamp"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "heartbeat"
    },      
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        dataPoints:""       
    }]
});

let xVal = 0;
let yVal = 100; 
let updateInterval = 1000;
let dataLength = 20; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

let updateChart = function (count) {

    count = count || 1;

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "POST",
    url= "https://asia-northeast1-unity-visualization.cloudfunctions.net/getHeartbeat";

    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data.length)
        }
    };
    queryJSON = {"uuid": "1541061643202"};
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(queryJSON));


    if (dps.length > dataLength) {
        dps.shift();
        //let dps = getElementById("uuid");
        //let dps = queryJSON;
    }

    function addData(chart, label, data) {
        chart.data.labels.push(label);
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((queryJSON) => {
            dataset.data.push(data);
        });
        chart.update();
    }

    chart.render();
};

updateChart(dataLength);
setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

}
```

Comment: What is tagged with chart.js?

Comment: This is JavaScript program which will run the scatter chart.